# Installing vue-cli with a lot of deprecated dependencies?

Tags: vue.js, npm

Haven't used Vue in a year and now I am trying to remember some of it, but it seems very strange even when installing it.

```
george@george-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

I've installed it with `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`.

Is this ok ? It doesn't look right.

Comment: Those are just benign warnings intended for the package developer. I would just ignore it. Vue CLI still works anyway.

Comment: As mentioned above, here's a [link to a github issue discussing](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5690#issuecomment-829361113) this where a maintainer describes similar "expected" behavior.